# vercel API conflict with laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, vercel

I am trying to deploy my Laravel app on Vercel.

Here is the `RouteServiceProvider.php` code:

```
...
public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('apis')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
...
```

The code in my `api.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'this is an API';
});

Route::get('/person', function () {
    $person = [
        'first_name' => 'Sean',
        'last_name' => 'Pooley',
    ];
    return $person;
});
```

At local env, `localhost/api` and `localhost/api/person`, works fine but when I deploy it on Vercel, the api `myapp/api/person` doesn't work but `myapp/apis/person`, `myapp/apis/`, `myapp/api` display what I want.

I suspect that the route is always refer to Vercel instead of Laravel route because there is one directory `api` at the root, so whenever calling for `api` it will direct to that folder. So is there anyway to overcome this issue? Or only can use `apis` as the prefix at the Laravel?

Comment: so you have a folder named 'api' in your 'public' folder?

Comment: No, the `api` folder is at the root directory, which have a `index.php` file to tell vercel to forward request to normal `index.php` (at public/index.php). Why would you ask that? (curious

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue and found out that by removing the `api` prefix from `RouteServiceProvider.php` you can access both `/resource` and `/api/resource` endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

On Vercel, the `/api` directory is reserved for Serverless functions. There are some workarounds, if you still want to use that route for other code, like prefixing the route with an underscore `_` . Read [docs here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions#deploying-serverless-functions)